# "As evidenced by" or "as evident by"?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, past-participles

I have this sentence:

> Group theory is one of my favourite areas in mathematics, as evidenced by the fact that I chose to do two group theory modules in my undergraduate course.

I am wondering if it should be *evident* instead of *evidenced*.

Comment: 'As is evidenced by' is the fuller version. Less rarefied are 'as shown by' / 'as is shown by'. 'As demonstrated by' works in a scientific register. // Possibly even starchier are 'as exemplified by' etc and 'as epitomized by' etc. And as for 'as evinced by'....

Answer (score 20):

I believe the expressions should be "as evidenced by" and "as *is* evident *from*," respectively.

My preference, however, would be to opt for neither expression. Instead, I normally use "as demonstrated by." It's identical in meaning to the phrase you're trying to use, and there is little chance of either confusion or misuse, as is possible with the other expressions.

Answer (score 11):

My first thought was that *as evidenced by* is a "malapropism". But [*as **evinced** by* this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=as%20evidenced%20by,as%20evinced%20by&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,as%20evidenced%20by;,c0;.t1;,as%20evinced%20by;,c0)...

[image: A Google ngram chart showing high usage of "as evidenced by" against a very low utilization of "as evinced by" with near concurrent usage until 1860 (0.0000200%) at which time "as evidenced by" grew greatly and "as evinced by" declined to minimal usage.]

...I'm slightly out of touch with current usage.

However, I *do* still think *as **evident** by* is a latter-day malapropism - as shown by [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=as%20evinced%20by,as%20evident%20by&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,as%20evinced%20by;,c0;.t1;,as%20evident%20by;,c0), where usage falls far short of even *as **evinced** by*.

Comment: *Evidence* can be a verb; whether it is too archaic to use is a personal view. *Evident* cannot be, so *as evident by* is wrong, possibly an eggcorn.

Comment: One could use *as made evident by* perfectly grammatically (although it's not in nearly as common usage).

Answer (score 3):

In health care reports, it is always "as evidenced by".

Comment: Can you show some evidence for your claim?